# How to restart Apache on Linux

Tags: ssh, apache-http-server

In order for my php.ini changes to take effect I need to restart Apache.
I have never done this before and so wary of getting it wrong. After researching several sites it seems to me thre are a few ways to do this. Which is the simplest way for me to understand? I do not require a server restart..
It is Linux server and I am accessing with ssh (Terminal on Mac)
Many Thanks

Comment: i assume this question has more chances to be answered on AskUbuntu website

Comment: What Linux distro are you running?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu, Debian, what Linux OS?

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: Hi P_Moz, I'm in agreement with DrZoo, please provide what kind of distro you are running the Apache on as it would be easier to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways, depending on what Linux distro (and version), whether systemd is installed, etc.

But the one that ALWAYS works is to use apache2ctl -

First, check to make sure your new config is good

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

And if it reports that your syntax is OK, etc. then restart

```
apache2ctl restart
```

Prefix with sudo as needed... again, depends on your distribution, etc.